# Why Python BeautifulSoup returns a empty list?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm a rookie student of IT, I was trying to help my Friend with his job and I wanted to create a list of costumers he could serve (maybe exporting it in a file would be awesome too but I will think about it later I guess).

When I try to run the code it just returns an empty list, do you have any suggestions?

any suggestions/feedback would be highly appreciated!

Thank you!
(I know maybe it isn't the best code you have ever seen! so I apologize myself in advance!)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pprint

res = requests.get('https://www.paginebianche.it/toscana/li/gommisti.html')
res2 = requests.get('https://www.paginebianche.it/ricerca?qs=gommisti&dv=li&p=2')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(res2.text, 'html.parser')

links = soup.select('.org fn')
subtext = soup.select('.address')
links2 = soup2.select('.org fn')
subtext2 = soup2.select('.address')

mega_links = links + links2
mega_subtext = subtext + subtext2

def create_custom_hn(mega_links,mega_subtext):
  hn = []
  for links,address in enumerate(mega_links):
    title = links.getText()
    address= address.getText()
    hn.append({'title': title, 'address': address})
  return hn
 
pprint.pprint(create_custom_hn(mega_links,mega_subtext))
```

Comment: Perhaps try the selector `.org.fn` instead? Note the dot (.) before `fn`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selector `.org fn` is wrong, should be `.org.fn` to select all elements with class `org` and `fn`.

However, some items don't have `.address` so, your code produces skewed results. You can use this example to get title and addresses (in case of missing address, `-` is used):

```
import pprint
import requests
from itertools import chain
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


res = requests.get('https://www.paginebianche.it/toscana/li/gommisti.html')
res2 = requests.get('https://www.paginebianche.it/ricerca?qs=gommisti&dv=li&p=2')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(res2.text, 'html.parser')

hn = []

for i in chain.from_iterable([soup.select('.item'), soup2.select('.item')]):
    title = i.h2.getText(strip=True)
    addr = i.select_one('[itemprop="address"]')
    addr = addr.getText(strip=True, separator='\n') if addr else '-'
    hn.append({'title': title, 'address': addr})    

pprint.pprint(hn)
```

Prints:

```
[{'address': 'Via Don Giovanni Minzoni 44\n-\n57025\nPiombino (LI)',
  'title': 'CENTROGOMMA'},
 {'address': 'Via Quaglierini 14\n-\n57123\nLivorno (LI)',
  'title': 'F.LLI CAPALDI'},
 {'address': 'Via Ugione 9\n-\n57121\nLivorno (LI)',
  'title': 'PNEUMATICI INTERGOMMA GOMMISTA'},
 {'address': "Viale Carducci Giosue' 88/90\n-\n57124\nLivorno (LI)",
  'title': 'ITALMOTORS'},
 {'address': 'Piazza Chiesa 53\n-\n57124\nLivorno (LI)',
  'title': 'Lo Coco Pneumatici'},
 {'address': '-', 'title': 'PIERO GOMME'},
 {'address': 'Via Pisana Livornese Nord 95\n-\n57014\nVicarello (LI)',
  'title': 'GOMMISTA TRAVAGLINI PNEUMATICI'},
 {'address': 'Via Cimarosa 165\n-\n57124\nLivorno (LI)',
  'title': 'GOMMISTI CIONI AUTORICAMBI & SERVIZI'},
 {'address': 'Loc. La Cerretella, 219\n-\n57022\nCastagneto Carducci (LI)',
  'title': 'AURELIA GOMME'},
 {'address': 'Strada Provinciale Vecchia Aurelia 243\n'
             '-\n'
             '57022\n'
             'Castagneto Carducci (LI)',
  'title': 'AURELIA GOMME DI GIANNELLI SIMONE'},

...and so on.
```

Comment: Thank you so much! :)